# Add copyright info on export in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, metadata

I usually prefer not to add copyright information directly when taking photos with my camera. However, when exporting JPEGs with Lightroom, I would like the photos to contain copyright information. I couldn't see an option to add copyright information to my photos when exporting with Lightroom. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by copyright? Metadata or watermark?

Comment: I am talking about metadata

Comment: Related question: [Lightroom - How Do I find Photos that are Missing Copyright Metadata?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/61404)

Comment: Related question: [How do I autofill the copyright metadata for the current Lightroom catalog?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/67189)

Comment: Related question: [What format should I use to store photo copyright metadata in my JPG files?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/12149)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are two ways:

- Once a photo is imported into Lightroom, add copyright info from the library module. It will be included when you export the image.
- Create a preset with copyright information, and apply it on import. This will mean all your photos will have the metadata already in the Lightroom DB.

The second option is what I use since all cameras do not support embedded copyright info. It also lets me once a year update the preset to have the current year in the copyright metadata.